# XPath Get Next Item

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xpath

I just started using XPATH, and I have some questions regarding it's functionality / whether it can do what I want it do. I have the following structure in my XML Document:

```
<root>
  <top id="1">
    <item id="1">
       <sub id="A"></sub>
       <sub id="B"></sub>
    <item>
    <item id="2">
       <sub id="A"></sub>
       <sub id="B"></sub>
    <item>
  </top>
  <top id="2">
    <item id="1">
       <sub id="A"></sub>
       <sub id="B"></sub>
    <item>
    <item id="2">
       <sub id="A"></sub>
       <sub id="B"></sub>
       <sub id="C"></sub>
    <item>
  </top>
</root>
```

I have the CurrentTop, CurrentItem, and CurrentSub stored in a variable.

```
var CurrentTop = "1", CurrentItem = "1", CurrentSub = "A";
```

Using an XPath query, I'd like to be able to select the next Sub regardless of where it is in the document, and if the next Sub is not in the same Item as the CurrentItem, I need to get that information as well. Same goes for Top

I am using Javascript. I understand that this might need to be done in Multiple Queries.

For Example:
The Next Items Would be (In Order):

```
TOP ITEM SUB

1   1    A
1   1    B
1   2    A
1   2    B
2   1    A
2   1    B
2   2    A
2   2    B
2   2    C
```

I am willing to accept suggestions as to how to improve the XML Document format as well.

If it helps, I'm also using NodeJS, the XPath Module, and the XMLDOM Module available on NPM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know node.js, but in XPath you can use [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Axes/following) axis to get element after current context element regardless of the target element being in the same parent or not. For example, to get the nearest `sub` element following current context element you can use this expression :

```
following::sub[1]
```

Contrasts with [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis which can only find element after current context element within the same parent.